# Where VIM keep its recordings?

Tags: file, macvim

I was trying to use VIM and it kept blinking "recording" all the time. Now I know that it means VIM was recording what I was typing. Where does it keep these recordings? I would like to delete these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "recording" label usually appears when you press 'q' key to record a macro. It is not recording what you are typing, it is recording a command sequence to be re-used for later use.

See: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros

Comment: Is there anyway I can clean this command sequence?

Comment: To start recording you press 'q' and a letter, to stop press 'q' again. Macros are NOT saved in between sessions so VIM will forget about it once you quit.

If you wish to expressly save a macro then read on http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros#Saving_a_macro

Comment: Oh... I got it. Thks!!

Answer (score 0):

The recordings are stored in the named buffers. You can place the buffer contents into a file as text, save the file, and reload the text into a buffer in another session. You can use the same technique to clean up the recorded macro. Insert the buffer as text, edit the text, re-save the text into the same buffer.